# how do i make a functional music seeker

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

How can i make a music player seeker that changes the song currentTime as i click on the progress bar.

[image]

```
progressContainer.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{  

    let clickX= e.clientX;
    let duration= audio.duration
    audio.currentTime= clickX/duration *100

})
```

this is what i have tried but it functions weirdly and unexpectedly.
what is a better way of doing this..

Comment: Hello @Sumit, Did you try with the onChange event ?

Comment: How specifically does it behave; what is weird and unexpected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set seconds you want the audio to play from

```
const progressContainerWidth = 100; // update accordingly
progressContainer.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{  
    const clickX= e.clientX;
    const fractionToSeekTo = clickX / progressContainerWidth;
    const duration= audio.duration
    audio.currentTime= duration * fractionToSeekTo;
})
```